# Link an existing app to a B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have set up B2C within my Azure Active Directory and linked it to my subscription.

When I go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ I have an app which I want to connect to the B2C account

However, the only option I appear to have on portal.azure.com is to add a new app

How do I link this B2C tenancy to that existing app pls?

Comment: Do you just want to make that application to multi-tenant and use it in your B2C tenant? Such as added it into Enterprise applications?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's just a gateway to apps I've already created. What I basically want to do is leverage GraphAPI for getting a token, and then my own AAD API for product functionality. Everything already 'works' using the older 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Clients' library but I am trying to utilise the latest offering

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't move an app between Azure AD tenants.

When you create a new app it creates an [application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects#application-object) in the Azure AD tenant owning it that can't be moved.

You need to create a new application in the other tenant and link your app to reference it instead.